# How to sort such a complex list in python?

Tags: python

```
x = [([('x', 2), ('m', 3)], 'a'), ([('y', 4), ('t',8), ('d', '100')], 'c'), ([('a', 1)], 'b')]
```

I want to sort by the inner tuple integer, i.e. 2, 4, 1. So the sorted list should be:

```
sorted_x = [(('a', 1), 'b'), (('x', 2), 'a'), (('y', 4), 'c')]
```

It should look like something like this:

```
x_sorted = sorted(x, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

But the tup[1] is for the first level of tuple, and I can write tup[tupe[1]].

I think I need to flatten the list first, and then sort it.

EDIT:

Thanks for the solution for the very complex list sorting. It turns out that I should actually sort this (sorry for the problem statement modification):

```
x = ([('x', 2), ('m', 3), ('n', 1)], 'a')
```

Result:

```
sorted_x = ([('n', 1), ('x', 2), ('m', 3)], 'a')
```

I tried this:

```
x_sorted = sorted(x, key=lambda tup: tup[0][1])
```

But get this error:

```
x_sorted = sorted(x, key=lambda tup: tup[0][1])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: ```sorted(x, key=lambda tup:tup[0][1])```

Comment: @ling Please add expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> x = [([('x', 2), ('m', 3)], 'a'), ([('y', 4), ('t',8), ('d', '100')], 'c'), ([('a', 1)], 'b')]

>>> sorted([(a[0],b) for [*a],b in x], key = lambda x:x[0][1])
# or, sorted([(a,c) for [a,*b],c in x], key = lambda x:x[0][1])

[(('a', 1), 'b'), (('x', 2), 'a'), (('y', 4), 'c')]
```

This works as:

```
>>> [(a[0],b) for [*a],b in x]
[(('x', 2), 'a'), (('y', 4), 'c'), (('a', 1), 'b')]
```

`[*a]` receives the list in each tuple, and `b` receives the other element, so for first element:

```
[*a] == [('x', 2), ('m', 3)]   # b = 'a'
a == (('x', 2), ('m', 3))
a[0] == ('x', 2)
```

A more explicit version would be:

```
>>> sorted([(inner_tup_1,other_elem) 
             for [inner_tup_1,*other_inner_tups], other_elem in x 
           ], key = lambda x:x[0][1])
```

**EDIT**:

```
>>> x = ([('x', 2), ('m', 3), ('n', 1)], 'a')
>>> a, b = ([('x', 2), ('m', 3), ('n', 1)], 'a')
>>> (sorted(a, key = lambda x:x[1]), b)
([('n', 1), ('x', 2), ('m', 3)], 'a')
```

The second line is called `unpacking`:

```
a, b = (1, 2) # implies a == 1, and b == 2
# similarly,
a, b = ([('x', 2), ('m', 3), ('n', 1)], 'a')
       -------------------------------  ---
                1st elem of tuple     2nd elem
# implies a == [('x', 2), ('m', 3), ('n', 1)] and b == 'a'
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x:x[1])
[('n', 1), ('x', 2), ('m', 3)]
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x:x[1]),  b
  ( [('n', 1), ('x', 2), ('m', 3)], 'a' )
```

For more on unpacking see [`PEP 3132`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and [`PEP 448`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) .

Comment: I guess it should be `lambda x:int(x[0][1])` right? If you want to sort based on integers

Comment: What about the ('t',8), ('d', '100')? They are missing from the sorted result?

Comment: @Ch3steR true, IF needs to be sorted by integers, however, to get the expected result this was enough.

Comment: @ling provided solution for expected output: `sorted_x = [(('a', 1), 'b'), (('x', 2), 'a'), (('y', 4), 'c')]`, I will update for the next case

Comment: yes. Please provide one fort he edited list. Which is simpler but is my real data.

Comment: @ling added, please check. If it solved your query, you may accept as a solution.

Comment: @Ch3steR did not see the requirement of using the integers before, updated it. Thanks.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Not a problem. Now +1.